# Two pop up alerts in same window

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to get two pop up alerts in the same window,

but with the 2nd alert function, the program runs but when clicked on the button, crashes with error

Error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    let title = "Display Title"
    let message = "You just clicked on Display Alert"
    let okText = "OK"

    let title1 = "Display Title"
    let message1 = "You just clicked on Display Alert"
    let okText1 = "OK"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)

    let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "title1", message: "message1", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton1 = UIAlertAction(title: okText1, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton1)


    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    presentViewController(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: You used `"title1"` and `"message1"` as string literals instead of variables and you added `okayButton1` to `alert` instead of `alert1`. Is this intentional?

Comment: I have corrected my mistakes, now the program does not crash... But there is no 2nd pop up alert.. only the first alert appears each time

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have to declare the same 3 strings twice?

Comment: I am just trying to find a way, if it possible to work without the same strings twice ? if yes could you please let me know how to work with ? what codes should I use ?

Comment: You could just pass the same variables to the function twice (`UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, ...`). Also, you say that "only the first alert appears each time". How do you know this? The alerts show the same text, therefore the two are indistinguishable.

Comment: var title = "Display Title"
        var message = "You just clicked on Display Alert"
        var okText = "OK"

        
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okayButton)

Comment: what's wrong with the code this time ? coz it's giving error this time : definition conflicts with previous

Comment: It's in the error message: `definition conflicts with previous`. You declared `alert` twice. I said you could use the `title`, `message`, and `okText` variables twice, but you can't _declare_ two variables with the same name twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display ony one **UIAlertController** at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [TKSwarmAlert](https://github.com/entotsu/TKSwarmAlert) custom control, but you won't have close buttons.